# Java не видит класс

Tags: java, классы

Всем привет, 2 день обучения Java и тут столкнулся с проблемой, компилятор не видит мой класс(пробовал создать дополнительный класс, а в нем `main`, но тоже не помогло).

Текст ошибки:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem: The constructor Marine() is undefined

Указываю параметры для конструктора:

```
Marine Test = new Marine(abc,qwe,asd,fds,qwe);
```

пишет:

> имя_параметра cannot be resolved to a variable

и

> The constructor Marine() is undefined

это при наведения на ошибку в консоле, та же ошибка.

Если удалить конструктор, то ошибка исчезнет, но суть задания именно в конструкторе.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Math.*;
import java.util.Random;
import java.lang.String;


public class Marine {

public static String name_unit;
public static String name_ship;
public static String type_of_ship;
public static String date;
public static String operating_time;
public static String personnel;
public static String place; 
public static boolean result;

public Marine(String name_unit, String name_ship, String type_of_ship, 
String date, String operating_time  ) {
    this.name_unit = name_unit;
    this.name_ship = name_ship;
    this.type_of_ship =  type_of_ship;
    this.date = date ;
    this.operating_time = operating_time;               
}

public String GetName_Unit() {
    return name_unit;
}

public void SetName_Unit(String name_unit) {
    this.name_unit = name_unit;
}

public String GetType_Of_Ship() {
    return type_of_ship;
}

public void set(String type_of_ship) {
    this.type_of_ship = type_of_ship;
}
public String GetDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String GetOperating_time() {
    return operating_time;
}

public void setOperating_time(String operating_time) {
    this.operating_time = operating_time;
}

public String GetPersonnel() {
    return personnel;
}

public void setPesonnel(String personnel) {
    this.personnel = personnel;
}

public String GetPlace() {
    return place;
}

public void setPlace(String place) {
    this.place = place;
}

public boolean GetResult() {
    return result;
}

public void setResult(boolean result) {
    this.result = result;
}

public String toString() {
    return "Название части: " + name_unit + " Название корабля: " + 
name_ship + " Тип корабля: "+ type_of_ship +
            " Дата учений: " + date + " Наработка: " + operating_time + " 
Кол-во личного состава: " + personnel +
            " Место проведения: " + place + " Результат учений: " + result ;
}

public static void main (String[] args) {

    Marine Test = new Marine(); // вот здесь ошибка, пишет класс не 
//определен

}       
}
```

Comment: Полный текст ошибки добавьте к вопросу.

Comment: Для начала, создайте отдельный файл для этого класса, и поместите код класса туда. Правый клик на пакете проекта - создать класс!

Comment: А вообще, когда вы пишите Marine Test = new Marine(); вы вызываете конструктор класса без параметров - скобки пусты (). А в вашем конструкторе имеется несколько параметров - public Marine(String name_unit, String name_ship, String type_of_ship, 
String date, String operating_time  ), либо укажите их при вызове конструктора, либо добавьте ещё один конструктор без параметров.

Comment: Ну и пользуйтесь подсказками вашего IDE (например NetBeans), это просто.

Comment: Вот полный текст ошибки:                                                    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The constructor Marine() is undefined

 at Marine.Marine.main(Marine.java:89)

Comment: The constructor Marine() is undefined  - это как раз и значит, что у вас нету такого конструктора, ваш конструктор требует указать несколько переменных типа String, а вы запускаете его без них.

Comment: Указываю параметры для конструктора ( Marine Test = new Marine(abc,qwe,asd,fds,qwe);) пишет "имя_параметра cannot be resolved to a variable" и "The constructor Marine() is undefined" это при наведения на ошибку в консоле, та же ошибка

Comment: Вы указываете параметры без кавычек, это означает, что под каждым из них вы имеете в виду некоторую переменную, которая содержит значение необходимого параметра, а таких переменных у вас в коде нет. Если вам нужно указать параметры типа String напрямую, то каждый из них нужно заключить в кавычки.

Comment: Все получилось!!!Спасибо Вам огромное Виталий, прям выручили, без вас, я бы еще пол дня просидел, примитивная ошибка с моей стороны!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию у класса есть конструктор без параметров, который Вы и вызываете в main, но как только мы добавляем любой другой конструктор, нам нужно добавить его вручную, т. к. конструктор без параметров, который не делает ничего, больше не считается валидным.
Обычно имена в java пишутся CamelCase, при этом имена переменных и методов с маленькой буквы.
Инициализировать статические поля в конструкторе не стоит. Тем более делать для них не статические геттеры и сеттеры. Потому как статические поля доступны без создания экземпляра класса. Лучше создать класс Marine в отдельном файле, сделать все его поля private без static. А в классе, в котором находится метод main, сделать его импорт, создать через один из доступных конструкторов и взаимодействовать с ним через открытые public методы.

Answer (score 0):

Пропишите класс ваш класс отдельно от выполняемого класса с методом `main`
В исполняемый класс импортируйте созданный вами класс и
передайте в методе `main` в конструктор параметры экземпляра, либо сделайте перегрузку конструктора без параметров, но при этом обязательно инициализировать поля класса что бы все они не были null.